# how to retieve min value from different table

Tags: sql

I want to retrieve min value of (time1) from `table1` and `table2` for example

```
table 1(id, time1, time2, time3)
table2(id, time1,time2,time3)
```

```
id , time 1, time2, time3 (after union)
1, 2:00pm,1:30pm,1:31pm
1,1:45pm, 3:00pm,4:00pm
2,2:01pm,1:31pm,1:32pm
2,1:50pm, 3:01pm,4:00pm
```

What I want at the final result is

```
id, time 1, time2, time3 
1,1:45pm, 3:00pm,4:00pm
2,1:50pm, 3:01pm,4:00pm
```

I tried as the following but I got duplicate ID which is min(time1) value from both table1 and table2. How can i get min(time1) row from union result as above example?

```
SELECT id,time1,time2,time3 FROM
Table1
WHERE time1 =
(
SELECT Min(time1)
FROM Table1
)
UNION
SELECT id,time1,time2,time3 FROM
Table2
WHERE time1 =
(
SELECT Min(time1)
FROM Table2
)
```

really appreciate for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to retieve min value from different table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281810/how-to-retieve-min-value-from-different-table)

Comment: What types are time 1, time2, time3 and what rdbms are you using?

Comment: Why are you posting the exact same question that you posted 30 minutes ago?  You should edit your original question with additional details if you are not getting answers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and sorry for my bad.. this is my first time posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can `union` the tables together, and group them by `id`:

```
select  id
,       min(time1) as min_time1
,       min(time2) as min_time2
,       min(time3) as min_time3
from    (
        select  id
        ,       time1
        ,       time2
        ,       time3
        from    table1
        union all
        select  id
        ,       time1
        ,       time2
        ,       time3
        from    table2
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        id
```